# Invalid package count or invalid package sequence number in C# with Fedex ShipService WSDL

Tags: c#, web-services, fedex

I have some code with Fedex webservice ShipService. But, when I run a console I get error code 2021 is: Invalid package count or invalid package sequence number.

I was add request.RequestedShipment.PackageCount = "1"; in my code. But it's not working.

Here my code:

```
private static void SetShipmentDetails(ProcessShipmentRequest request)
    {
        request.WebAuthenticationDetail = lFedex.SetWebAuthenticationDetail();
        //
        request.ClientDetail = lFedex.SetClientDetail();
        //
        request.TransactionDetail = new TransactionDetail();
        request.TransactionDetail.CustomerTransactionId = "***Freight Domestic Ship Request using VC#***"; // The client will get the same value back in the response
        //
        request.Version = new VersionId();
        //
        request.RequestedShipment = new RequestedShipment();
        request.RequestedShipment.ShipTimestamp = DateTime.Now; // Ship date and time
        request.RequestedShipment.DropoffType = DropoffType.REGULAR_PICKUP;
        request.RequestedShipment.ServiceType = "FEDEX_FREIGHT_PRIORITY"; // Service types are STANDARD_OVERNIGHT, PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT, ...
        request.RequestedShipment.PackagingType = "YOUR_PACKAGING"; // Packaging type FEDEX_BOK, FEDEX_PAK, FEDEX_TUBE, YOUR_PACKAGING, ...
        //
        SetSender(request);
        //
        SetRecipient(request);
        //
        SetPayment(request);
        //
        request.RequestedShipment.DeliveryInstructions = "FreightDeliveryInstructions";
        //
        SetLabelDetails(request);
        //
        SetShippingDocumentDetails(request);
        //
        SetFreightShipmentDetail(request);
        //
        request.RequestedShipment.PackageCount = "1";
    }
```

Pls, help me!

Comment: I think a weight is required.  Check documentation : https://www.fedex.com/us/developer/downloads/pdf/2018/FedEx_WebServices_DevelopersGuide_v2018.pdf

Comment: I was add weight in Dimensions and in FreightShipmentDetail but isn't working

Comment: Are you getting same error?  I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the ShipService request with the API request.  The ShipService is probably setting more parameters than you code.  The error number are at the end of pdf link I provided.  Error 2021 is the country information